# Base resistor on BC817-40

Tags: transistors, calculation, base

There are base resistor calculators and multiple questions are answered on the subject of base resistor calculation. However, the [BC817-40](https://www.mccsemi.com/pdf/Products/BC817-16%7EBC817-40(SOT-23).pdf) I am using from MCC is showing two different gains (HFE1 and HFE2). That is confusing me to do the calculation of the base resistor.

I have 3 IR LEDs (Vishay TSAL4400) with 100 mA forward current that I want to drive using the BC817-40. I plan give 80 mA to each LED, so I need a total of 240 mA collector current. A microcontroller's GPIO (3.3 V) will be used to drive the transistor's base.

Can you please help me find the right base resistor value for the BC817-40 to drive around 250 mA current? Voltage at the collector is 5 V; it will be used to drive the IR LED.

Comment: If you want to drive 250mA load, you approximately need 25mA base current. Is your microcontroller even rated to provide 25mA? Just checking if it is even possible to do what you want, even if you have calculated the base resistor.

Comment: Try RB < 1K for example 470R and 33R in series with the IR diodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that CMOS logic outputs are current sources by design, I'd use no base resistor at all. This ensures that you'll get the highest possible base current to saturate that fairly small transistor.

Many MCUs have variable GPIO output strength, so you could adjust between low/[medium]/high drive strength to fine-tune it. The worst-case condition is when things are cold, so you'd want to stick it in a regular household freezer at least, measure the IR LED current, and select the GPIO drive level that ensures that the LEDs get the current they need.

Alternatively, use a Darlington connection. This will put little thermal load on the MCU pin drivers, and is meant to work across full temperature range that the transistors are rated for.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsWS51.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

The specified h<sub>FE</sub> values are for V<sub>CE</sub> = 1 V, which you do not want. You want to saturate the transistor, and as shown in figures 3 and 4, this should be done with β = 10. So R = (3.3 V − 0.9 V) / 24 mA = 100 Ω.

This assumes that your microcontroller actually has enough drive strength for this, which is unlikely. You could use multiple GPIOs in parallel (as long as you ensure that they are switched at the same time), or use a MOSFET, e.g., TN0606/TN0104/TN0702.

Comment: There is nothing special about a beta of 10. They just chose this number to test the Vce(sat). Some other vendors test the Vce(sat) at beta = 20. Thus, a forced beta of around 20 to 50 will do the job as well.

Answer (score 0):

@G36 you are probably right about the saturation beta values, but if you plot the IV curve of the transistor, you will notice that a beta below 20 guarantees the transistor is saturated (please refer to the LTSpice charts below). I have added the 1.5R resistor to limit the collector current to its maximum allowed value.
In the chart, the saturation starts at base current of 10mA. By the time the time the base current reaches 50mA you can see the beta below 10 in the top chart Ic(Q1)/Ib(Q1)

Thanks.

[image]